# Cron job to delete files older than 3 days

Tags: shell-script, files, cron, rm, timestamps

I need to remove files older than 3 days with a cron job in 3 different directories. (these 3 directories are children of a parent directory `/a/b/c/1` & `/a/b/c/2` & `/a/b/c/3`)  Can this be done with one line in the crontab?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is easy enough (although note that this goes by a modification time more than 3 days ago since a creation time is only available on certain filesystems with special tools):

```
find /a/b/c/1 /a/b/c/2 -type f -mtime +3 #-delete
```

Remove the `#` before the `-delete` once you are sure that it is finding the files you want to remove.

To have it run by cron, I would probably just create an executable script (add a shebang - `#!bin/sh` to the top line of the file and make executable with `chmod a+x`), then put it in an appropriate `cron` directory like `/etc/cron.daily` or `/etc/cron.weekly`. Provided of course that you do not need a more specific schedule and that these directories exist on your distro.

#### Update

As noted below, the `-delete` option for `find` isn't very portable. A POSIX compatible approach would be:

```
find /a/b/c/1 /a/b/c/2 -type f -mtime +3 #-exec rm {} +
```

Again remove the `#` when you are sure you have the right files.

#### Update2

To quote from [Stéphane Chazelas comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136804/cron-job-to-delete-files-older-than-3-days/136807?noredirect=1#comment218309_136807) below:

> Note that `-exec rm {} +` has race condition vulnerabilities which `-delete` (where available) doesn't have. So don't use it on directories that are writeable by others. Some finds also have a `-execdir` that mitigates against those vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to specify the parent directory and then the child directories so the `/a/b/c/` doesn't have to be specified for every option?

Comment: Sure, in a POSIX shell you can do `/a/b/c/[12]`, but this is only really appropriate if the subdirectories have single letter names. In `bash` you can do `/a/b/c/{1,2}`. Of course then the bang line for a script would have to be `#!/bin/bash` or if you are using crontab, you need to make sure it is configured to use `bash` (I don't really recommend changing it if it isn't).

Comment: brace expansion is a csh feature and is also supported by ksh, bash, zsh and fish so you have a wide choice of shells. `ksh`, `bash` and `zsh` also have alternation operators in their globs. Note that `-exec rm {} +` has race condition vulnerabilities which `-delete` (where available) doesn't have. So don't use it on directories that are writeable by others. Some finds also have a `-execdir` that mitigates against those vulnerabilities.

Comment: Does `rm -f` not handle errors silently, thereby handling any possible race condition with `-exec`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, could you please link to a more full explanation of the race condition you mentioned?  I'm interested.

Comment: @Wildcard, see for instance [Why did find with -delete erase the files in my /save/ directory when find without delete was not able to locate them?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/256758) or [how to delete (or keep) certain file extensions using busybox find?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/269660)

Answer (score 9):

You would be much better off using `tmpwatch`

```
tmpwatch recursively removes files which haven't been accessed for a given time. Normally, it's used to clean up directories which are used for temporary holding space such as /tmp.
```

Comment: `tmpwatch` has been forked to `tmpreaper`, which (at least on Debian) seems to be it's replacement.