# how to delete (or keep) certain file extensions using busybox find?

Tags: find, busybox

I have a folder which contains files (various file extensions) and subfolders. I want to keep certain file extensions and delete the rest.

```
e.g. keep all .txt and .jpg files and delete all other files.
```

on regular UNIX/GNU, I can use  find together with the "-not" parameter to achieve this.

```
> find . -not -name "*.jpg" -not -name "*txt" -type f -delete
```

But sadly, this parameter is not available on busybox find.

Any ideas on how it can be done? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-not` and `-delete` are non-standard extensions.

There's no reason why you'd want to use `-not`, when there's a shorter standard equivalent: `!`.

For `-delete`, you'll have to invoke `rm` with the `-exec` predicate:

```
find . ! -name '*.jpg' ! -name '*.txt' -type f -exec rm -f '{}' +
```

(if you have an older version of busybox, you may need the `-exec rm -f '{}' ';'` which runs one `rm` per file).

That command above is standard, so will work not only in busybox but also with other non-GNU modern implementations of `find`.

Note that on GNU systems at least, that command (with any `find` implementation as long as it uses GNU `fnmatch(3)`) may still remove some files whose name ends in `.jpg` or `.txt`, as the `*.jpg` pattern would fail to match files whose name contains invalid characters in the current locale.

To work around that, you'd need:

```
LC_ALL=C find . ! -name '*.jpg' ! -name '*.txt' -type f -exec rm -f '{}' +
```

Also note that contrary to GNU's `-delete`, that approach won't work in very deep directory trees as you would then end up reaching the maximum size of a file path passed to the `unlink()` system call. AFAIK, with `find`, there's no way around that if your `find` implementation doesn't support `-execdir` nor `-delete`.

You may also want to read the [security considerations discussed in the GNU `find` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Security-Considerations-for-find.html#Security-Considerations-for-find) if you're going to run that command in a directory writable by others.

Comment: I'm eager to find out wheter OP's version of `find` supports `!`. I kind of assumed it's not since `-not` was not supported.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, hardly any `find` implementation supports `-not` (an extension added to GNU find in 2.0 in 1990, sometimes added later to  other implementations like FreeBSD in 2002 for compatibility with GNU find). They all support `!` though and have had since the very first version of Unix in 1970.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev (continued) what the OP's find might miss is support for `-exec {} +` which was added recently to busybox `find`.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, actually the early Unix find implementations didn't take any option, all the `-name`, `!`... were added later on in the 70s.

Comment: It should have been hard to use it then, considering one couldn't post-process the output.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, there was no `xargs` then. Also, the persons using those systems at the time were usually the same as those writing software for them, and on a million $ system which was a privilege to be able to use, you wouldn't fool around creating filenames with spaces in them let alone newline, especially considering the max length of a filename was pretty short. The situation has evolved quite a bit since then.

Comment: With regard to the line "AFAIK...there's no way around that," perhaps it's a silly idea, but couldn't you use `find ... -exec sh -c 'cd "$(dirname "$0")"; rm -f "$(basename "$0")"' {} \;`?  Or more safely (in case of trailing newlines in dir names), `find ... -exec sh -c 'cd "${0%/*}"; rm -f "${0##*/}"' {} \;`?

Comment: @Wildcard, that would have to be `zsh -c ...` as `zsh` seems to be the only shell that breaks down the `cd` into several `chdir()`s when the path is too long.

Answer (score 1):

Busybox `find` [claims](https://busybox.net/BusyBox.html#find) to support `-regex` option, which you could use to remove files which *do match* the pattern:

```
find . -type f -regex '.*\.tmp\|.*\.core' -delete
```

Unfortunately, excluding a list of extensions without the `-not` option is not possible in the general case (technically, [there is a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2218072/4350586), but it doesn't scale). That's the reason to include the `-not` option in the first place. If you need to exclude an arbitrary list of extensions, you'll need a `find` which supports this option, or `find`+`grep`+`xargs`:

```
find . | grep -v -e '\.jpg$' -e '\.txt$' | xargs rm
```

Comment: You can't post-process the output of `find .` unless you can make some assumptions on what characters the filename may contain. It's even worse when piping to `xargs` as  in addition to newline, you'd also have problems with blanks, quotes and backslashes.