# Cron job to delete all files older than 7 days: -exec rm -f {} \; vs -delete

Tags: cron, rm, delete

I want to run a cron job which deletes `.txt` files older than 7 days. I have two commands.
The first command:

```
/usr/bin/find /var/www/example.com/wp-content/targetdir -name "*.txt" -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

The second command:

```
/usr/bin/find /var/www/example.com/wp-content/targetdir -name "*.txt" -type f -mtime +7 -delete
```

Both the commands can be used be delete `.txt` files older than 7 days. I have read that the first command is associated with a `race condition`. Can one please elaborate the advantages of using the second command over the first command? What are the pros and cons of using one above the other?

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/q/1222165/432690).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The race I saw mentioned is this, from [Stéphane Chazelas's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136804/cron-job-to-delete-files-older-than-3-days#comment218309_136807) to another question:

> Note that `-exec rm {} +` has race condition vulnerabilities which `-delete` (where available) doesn't have. So don't use it on directories that are writeable by others. Some finds also have a `-execdir` that mitigates against those vulnerabilities.

I didn't actually see this elaborated there<sup>(*)</sup>, but the race I can see there relates to how `-exec rm` passes the full path to the file, causing the tree to be traversed again within the `rm` process.

After `find` traverses the tree and evaluates the conditions it's given on the command line, `rm` traverses the tree again, and it doesn't know about the conditions given to `find`, so now they are not checked. With `-delete` and `-execdir` , `find` traverses the tree, makes whatever checks it's given, and then deletes the file, all the time keeping a file descriptor open on the directories.

Someone could get in between and rename a file or directory between `find` evaluating its conditions and `rm` running. So, something like this:

1. root runs `find . -type f -user joe -exec rm -f {} \;`
2. `find` runs and finds directory `./this/`, holding some files owned by user `joe`
3. another user renames `./this` and creates a symlink with the same name, pointing somewhere else
4. `find` runs `rm -f ./this/hello.txt`, now following the symlink.

`hello.txt` could now be owned by anyone, not just user `joe`, and since `find` was launched as `root`, `rm` also is, and it happily removes the file at the other end of the symlink. This is a classic [time-of-check to time-of-use (TOCTTOU) vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use).

One can probably come up worse examples, but that's a general idea.

With `-delete` or `-execdir`, this can't happen, since the file descriptor `find` has open on `./this` still points to the same directory, even if that directory is renamed. `-execdir` runs `rm` with it's working directory set to that directory (there's the `fchdir()` system call that changes the working directory by file descriptor, again not going through a name lookup), while `-delete` similarly deletes the using a name relative to the containing directory (with `unlinkat()`).

Note that by default (i.e. without the `-L` option), `find` doesn't follow symlinks found when traversing the directory tree. This doesn't help here, since again `rm` just passes the path it was given to the underlying system call, and symlinks are followed there as usual. It does mean that the replaced directory (`./this` above) has to be an actual directory replaced with a symlink (or another directory) though, not a symlink replaced by another symlink.

<sup>(*)</sup>20 minutes after writing this, I noticed  Stéphane's answer (linked below) did have [a link to the GNU manual describing the same race issue](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Race-Conditions-with-_002dexec.html). (sigh.)

---

The issues with `-delete` implying `-depth`, and making `-prune` ineffective
is unrelated to that, and not a race condition. This is mentioned in [Why did find with -delete erase the files in my /save/ directory when find without delete was not able to locate them?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/256757/170373) GNU coreutils `find` seems to have acquired an error message for that:

```
$ find a -name foo -prune -o -name hello.txt -delete
find: The -delete action automatically turns on -depth, but -prune does nothing when -depth is in effect.  If you want to carry on anyway, just explicitly use the -depth option.
```

Another difference is that `-exec rm -f -- {} +` uses only standard tools, while `-delete` is not standard, even if somewhat commonly supported. E.g. FreeBSD and GNU support it, but Busybox doesn't. See: [find: "-exec rm {} ;" vs. "-delete" - why is the former widely recommended?](https://superuser.com/q/1222165/600133) on superuser.com.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the working of exec vs execdir? From your answer execdir sounds like a good option

Comment: @DawsonSmith, if you are in e.g. `/tmp/` and run `find . -type f -exec rm {} \;`, when that `./this/hello.txt` is encountered, find runs `rm ./this/hello.txt` from `/tmp`. But the same with `-execdir` changes directory to `./this` (`/tmp/this`) first, and then runs `rm hello.txt`. Since find has an fd open on `./this`, it can do it safely. It doesn't actually call `chdir("./test")`: that would involve the name lookup again; instead if calls `fchdir(fd_of_dir_currently_processed)`.

Comment: So, according to the above explanation, /usr/bin/find /var/www/example.com/wp-content/targetdir -name "*.txt" -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm -f {} \; and /usr/bin/find /var/www/example.com/wp-content/targetdir -name "*.txt" -type f -mtime +7 -execdir rm -f {} \; perform the same functionality but it's just that execdir is much safer because of no call to chdir

Comment: @DawsonSmith, yes. It's just the working directory of `rm` changing, with the corresponding change to the arg it gets. You can see that with something like `find ... -exec sh -c 'printf "pwd: $PWD\narg: $1\n"' sh {} \;`, compare with `-exec` vs. `-execdir`. Of course, as long as no-one modifies the tree in the meanwhile, it doesn't make much difference for `rm`.

Comment: One of the races is explained in the Q&A I linked to in my first comment above: directories can be replaced with symlinks (as shown in your scenario). This is where `execdir` helps, as you explain. It might be worth mentioning `find`’s default handling of symlinks, since that plays a part too.

Comment: @StephenKitt, yeah, I managed to miss that the first time when skimming over it. Just found the mention, as well as the link to the GNU manual explaining it in detail. Oh well, here it is anyway.

Comment: @StephenKitt, hmm... default handling is to not follow symlinks, right? So it would have to be an actually directory that was replaced with a symlink (or another directory), not just a symlink replaced by another? Is there something else?

Comment: @ilkkachu I can’t think of anything else, but it’s non-obvious enough to be worth mentioning, IMO — users relying on the fact that `find` won’t jump out of a directory tree can be in for a surprise.

Comment: @DawsonSmith `-execdir` is safer than `-exec`, but if you’re deleting files there’s no point in using `-execdir` instead of `-delete`.

Comment: @StephenKitt, though if they wanted to delete partial subtrees, then using `-execdir rm -rf -- {} \; -prune` instead of `-delete` could be useful. (depending on the conditions they want to set.) But with just files like here, `-delete` is simpler, like you said.